# docker-compose up, bad interpreter, is looking for the wrong path for python executable

Tags: python, docker-compose, linuxbrew

When I run docker-compose up

I get the error

`zsh: /home/emil/.local/bin/docker-compose: bad interpreter: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/bin/python: no such file or directory`

I checked which python and I get
`/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python`

I tried to system link

➜  2.7.16 ln -s /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/bin/python
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/bin/python': No such file or directory
➜  2.7.16 ln -s home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/bin/python /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python': File exists

At the moment linux brew python installation is at 2.7.16_1 folder not 2.7.16. How do I fix this ? I want to create link so whenever it looks for python at 2.7.16/bin/python it should rather look into 2.7.16_1/bin/python.

Is this even possible ?

And how can I solve this, any ideas ? I tried uninstalling and reinstalling docker and python.

Comment: please, share your docker-compose file and relevant Dockerfiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I uninstalled docker apt remove docker as it is suggested at their website

```sh
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
```

then I had installed docker and docker-compose using linuxbrew.

But it was still somehow using the `/home/username/.local/bin/docker-compose`, so I deleted it. I figured that once i ran docker-compose, it gave the same error but also ran successfully. Somehow it was running both of the executables.

So I just `rm /home/username/.local/bin/docker-compose` and it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

When installing a formula via brew it will symlink necessary binaries to a `bin` directory that's on your `PATH`. Try re-linking the formula:

```
brew link --overwrite python
```

Otherwise, [it appears](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/docker-compose) the `docker-compose` formula depends on python 3.

Comment: This did not work. I did use linuxbrew to install docker-compose but python. So it gave me the idea to try that.